# How to get input box enable in a row with onClick in that row - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have table with three input select and one button , so after I click on button I want to enable respective input to it, also change text of button and it should work individually for all rows, I have tried some methods but it doesn't very helpful.

```
  <input
                    placeholder=""
                    onChange={console.log("something")}
                    className="engineer-input"
                    disabled={true}
                  />
 {1 ? (
                    <button
                      className="btnassign"
                      onClick={console.log("show assign")}
                    >
                      Assign
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <button className="btnassign">Allocated</button>
                    </>
                  )}
```

Here is the link to code - https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-mendel-t94y70?file=/src/App.js:1650-2032

Comment: when clicked the `text` should change from "assigned" to "allocated" ?

Comment: yes, also all select in row should enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `state` to control the array of items, and on each item set a `boolean` property to control the `inputs` ( enabled/disabled ) and the `button` ( assign/allocated ).

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [engineers, setEngineers] = useState([
    {
      serviceDate: "01/01/2020",
      vesselName: "name",
      equipmentName: "eqName",
      noOfEngineers: 3,
      engineer1: "",
      engineer2: "",
      engineer3: "",
      active: false
    }
  ]);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="engineer-container">
        <div className="table">
          <div className="header">
            <div>Service Date</div>
            <div>Vessel Name</div>
            <div>Equipment Name </div>
            <div>
              No of <br /> Eng
            </div>
            <div>Engineer 1</div>
            <div>Engineer 2</div>
            <div>Engineer 3</div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>

          {engineers.map((item, index) => (
            <>
              <div className="row" key={index}>
                <div>{item.serviceDate}</div>
                <div>{item.vesselName}</div>
                <div>{item.equipmentName}</div>
                <div>{item.noOfEngineers}</div>
                <div>
                  <input
                    placeholder=""
                    value={item.engineer1}
                    onChange={console.log("something")}
                    className="engineer-input"
                    disabled={!item.active}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input
                    placeholder=""
                    value={item.engineer2}
                    onChange={console.log("something")}
                    className="engineer-input"
                    disabled={!item.active}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input
                    placeholder=""
                    value={item.engineer3}
                    onChange={console.log("something")}
                    className="engineer-input"
                    disabled={!item.active}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  {!item.active ? (
                    <button
                      className="btnassign"
                      onClick={() =>
                        setEngineers((prev) => {
                          prev[index].active = !prev[index].active;
                          return [...prev];
                        })
                      }
                    >
                      Assign
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <button className="btnassign">Allocated</button>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr className="horizental" />
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-dream-d6qy6i)

Answer (score 0):

You need a state, where you store your row id number with a flag in an array:

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([
  { id: 0, isEnabled: false },
  { id: 1, isEnabled: false },
  { id: 2, isEnabled: false },
  { id: 3, isEnabled: false },
  { id: 4, isEnabled: false },
  { id: 5, isEnabled: false },
  { id: 6, isEnabled: false }
]);
```

Create a handleClick function, where you change the flag by id:

```
const handleClick = id => {
  setRows(...);
};
```

Map through the array, use the flag for the input fields disabled prop, and use the handleClick function with the row id param:

```
rows.map(row => ...)

<input
  ...
  disabled={row.isEnabled}
  ...
/>

<button
  className="btnassign"
  onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}
>
  {!item.isEnabled ? "Assign" : "Allocated"}
</button>
```

I assume you will store the input field values in the state as well, so extend the state and write the handleChange logic for the fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can have some state to capture clicked button and have conditions based on that as:

`disabled={activeId === item ? false : true}`

**Full code...**

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState("");

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="engineer-container">
        <div className="table">
          <div className="header">
            <div>Service Date</div>
            <div>Vessel Name</div>
            <div>Equipment Name </div>
            <div>
              No of <br /> Eng
            </div>
            <div>Engineer 1</div>
            <div>Engineer 2</div>
            <div>Engineer 3</div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>

          {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((item, key) => (
            <React.Fragment key={item}>
              <div className="row" key={key}>
                <div>01/01/2020</div>
                <div>name</div>
                <div>eqName</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>
                  <input
                    placeholder=""
                    onChange={console.log("something")}
                    className="engineer-input"
                    disabled={activeId === item ? false : true}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input
                    placeholder=""
                    onChange={console.log("something")}
                    className="engineer-input"
                    disabled={activeId === item ? false : true}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input
                    placeholder=""
                    onChange={console.log("something")}
                    className="engineer-input"
                    disabled={activeId === item ? false : true}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  {!activeId ? (
                    <button
                      className="btnassign"
                      onClick={() => {
                        setActiveId(item);
                      }}
                    >
                      {"Assign"}
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <button
                        onClick={() => {
                          setActiveId(item);
                        }}
                        className="btnassign"
                      >
                        {activeId === item ? "Allocated" : "Assign"}
                      </button>
                    </React.Fragment>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr className="horizental" />
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```css
.engineer-container {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  /* margin: 20px 0; */
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(168, 166, 166);
}
.table {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.horizental {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.header div:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;

  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.header div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;

  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.header div:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1 0 15%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header div:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 1 0 5%;
  text-align: center;

  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.header div:nth-child(5) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;

  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.header div:nth-child(6) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;

  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.header div:nth-child(7) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;

  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.header div:nth-child(8) {
  flex: 1 0 5%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.header div:nth-child(9) {
  flex: 1 0 2%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.row div:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 2px;
  height: -1px;
}

.row div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 2px;
}

.row div:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1 0 15%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 2px;
  // text-align: center;
}

.row div:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 1 0 2%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 2px;
}

.row div:nth-child(5) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  /* font-size: 15px; */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  /* height: 0px; */
}

.engineer-input {
  outline: none;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.engineer-input {
  width: 80%;
  height: 25px;
  /* padding: 6px; */
  font-size: 15px;
}

.row div:nth-child(6) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  /* height: 0px; */
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
.engineer-input {
  outline: none;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.engineer-input {
  outline: none;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.row div:nth-child(7) {
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  /* height: 0px; */
}
.engineer-input {
  outline: none;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.engineer-input {
  width: 80%;
  /* padding: 6px; */
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.row div:nth-child(8) {
  flex: 1 0 5%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 5px;
}
button {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid rgb(151, 150, 150);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row div:nth-child(9) {
  flex: 1 0 2%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 2px;
}
img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

[image: Edit beautiful-tdd-g7539x]